# Slow query on mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I recently moved the database from mysql to mariadb, but the same query is executed in mysql in less than a second, but it takes 20 minutes in mariadb.

query :

```
SELECT km.beleg, km.art, ke.id as KID 
FROM buchhaltung.kosten_ersatz ke 
LEFT JOIN buchhaltung.konto_match km ON km.beleg = ke.id AND km.art IN (2,12,14,15,16) 
WHERE km.beleg IS NULL
```

`

show create table on mariadb (table `kosten_ersatz`):

[image]

show create table on mariadb (table `konto_match`):

[image]

Comment: please show us the `EXPLAIN SELECT..` of your query and please no images of code or data

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please note that you **should not** post images of text for the reasons outlined [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Please use formatted text - widget above edit box. You appear to have put `MariaDB` twice, instead of `MariaDB` for one `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `MySQL` for the other?

Answer (score 1):

Replace KEY beleg with

```
INDEX(beleg,  art)
```

Get rid of the `LEFT JOIN`, it will have no impact on the query results.  (I would expect MariaDB to do that automatically, but your evidence says the opposite.)

This may be the main problem:

```
ON km.beleg = ke.id
```

Note that one is a `VARCHAR`, the other is `INT`.  Not good for `JOINing`, as the `EXPLAIN` might hint at.